# How to predict a very large number M of xy coordinates?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, regression

I have dataset of 6000 samples.
Each sample has 121 points of x and y coordinates.
The dataset is like this (6000, 121, 2).

I need to predict 1464 points of xy coordinates. So what I need is to map the 121,2 input points into 1464,2 out points?
I have tried many approaches pure ANN,CNN, endcoder decoder.
However the results weren't satisfying.

Can you one has an idea how to solve such problem?

I have tried several approaches as ANN and CNN. However, there was somehow big difference between the predicted outputs and the labels.

Answer (score -1):

one way possible is simply session.run(), optimizer this example is for experiment and understanding of inputs shape where you can use layers and model too but feeds shape must be correct for training and predictions.

Sample: X and Y Co-ordinate learning, monitors the loss value, and prevent errors from unsatisfied conditions.

```
import os
from os.path import exists
import tensorflow as tf

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
learning_rate = 0.001
global_step = 0
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

X = np.arange(2, 6002, 1)
Y = np.arange(12, 3012, 0.5)
X = np.reshape( X, (1, 6000, 1))
Y = np.reshape( Y, (1, 6000, 1))

history = [ ] 
history_Y = [ ]

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Functions
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
# optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
    learning_rate,
    initial_accumulator_value=0.1,
    l1_regularization_strength=0.2,
    l2_regularization_strength=0.1,
    use_locking=False,
    name='ProximalAdagrad'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
var1 = tf.Variable(10.0)
var2 = tf.Variable(10.0)
X_var = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('X', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 6000, 1)))
y_var = tf.compat.v1.get_variable('Y', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random.normal((1, 6000, 1)))
Z = tf.nn.l2_loss((var1 - X_var) ** 2 + (var2 - y_var) ** 2, name="loss")

cosine_loss = tf.keras.losses.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(Z))
training_op = optimizer.minimize(cosine_loss(X_var, y_var))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
    
    # number of data feeds ( 6000 ==> 1000 )
    for i in range(1000):
        global_step = global_step + 1
        train_loss, temp = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={X_var:X, y_var:Y})
        history.append(train_loss)
        history_Y.append( history[0] - train_loss )
        
        x_value = X_var.eval()[0][i][0]
        y_value = y_var.eval()[0][i][0]
        v = Z.eval()
        
        print( 'x_value ' + str( x_value ) )
        print( 'y_value ' + str( y_value ) )
        print( 'v ' + str( v ) )
        
        print( 'steps: ' + str(i) )
    
    
    X2 = np.reshape([ 500, -400, 400, -300, 300, -200, 200, -100, 100, 1 ], (1, 10, 1))
    Y2 = np.reshape([ -400, 400, -300, 300, -200, 200, -100, 100, -50, 50 ], (1, 10, 1))
    X_var = X_var[:,:10:]
    y_var = y_var[:,:10:]
    
    for i in range(10):
        train_loss, temp = sess.run([loss, training_op], feed_dict={X_var:X2, y_var:Y2})
        x_value = X_var.eval()[0][i][0]
        y_value = y_var.eval()[0][i][0]
        v = Z.eval()
        
        print( 'x_value ' + str( x_value ) )
        print( 'y_value ' + str( y_value ) )
        print( 'v ' + str( v ) )
        
        print( 'steps: ' + str(i) )
        
sess.close()

plt.plot(history)
plt.plot(history_Y)
plt.show()
plt.close()

input('...')
```

Output: Target X and Y coordinate prediction, training tries to evaluate the var1, var2, loss values, and square errors.

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
x_value 0.36800474
y_value -0.53657633
v 121269736.0
steps: 883

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Predict
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
x_value -0.25996116
y_value 0.006405342
v 120543970.0
steps: 7
```

[image: Sample]